# What happens to S3 lambda notifications when the lambda is being updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that is updated by a continuous deployment process. The lambda is triggered by S3 notifications whenever an S3 object is created. It is important that no notifications are missed.

What do I need to be aware of triggering guarantees here?

For example, if the lambda is being updated when an S3 object is written, do all notifications still get processed?

Answer (score 3):

All notifications will be delivered to Lambda, irrespective of your deployment process. Lambda uses ALIASes to manage which version of the function is to be executed. All calls always go the the LATEST alias.

Let's say you have the version v1 deployed currently, so at this point LATEST=v1. Now when a deployment is in progress for v2, the alias LATEST still points to v1, so your notifications will get delivered. After the deployment is complete, the alias is changed to LATEST=v2.

Comment: "All calls always go the the LATEST alias." by default you mean - you can also specify an alias when you invoke a function;-)

Comment: Yes you can. You can create aliases to different versions of the Lambda functions. Each alias has its own ARN. You can invoke the alias by specifying its ARN instead of the Lambda function ARN.

Comment: There is another related question - what happens if the lambda fails to process the message. And even for that there is an answer https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/aws-lambda-supports-dead-letter-queues/